# Android performance on first launch

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack-compose

Why my app freezes for some time on the first launch?
For an example animations of screen transitions or collapsing toolbar freezes on first showing time. If I kill the app completely and open it again there is no issues with performance. It happens even with release build type

Answer (score 0):

If releasing a memory by killing your app helps to 'resolve' this issue, it a sign of memory leak. Do you use leak canary in your project (https://github.com/square/leakcanary)? If not, please add and test your app to figure out if there is a memory leak.

Freeze is also might mean some resource consuming task in the `MainThread`. Do you [use](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode) a `StrictMode`? If not, please add it and see reports\crash -- it will help you to figure out if you or 3rd party library execute *some* time consuming operations in the `MainThread`. However even if your app passes `StrictMode`, you still can have other types of *heavy* operations, e.g. solving a complex differential equation, in the `MainThread`

Finally, Android Studio provides a good tools for app performance analysis. Please [check them](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler) to find out less obvious performance issues.

Comment: I would also pay especial attention to 3rd party libraries defined on ```overrided onCreate()``` of the ```Application``` https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#app-creation

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to freeze your app, the most common is to already have a heavy task run in long time at main thread, such as: load a large photo resource, call a restful api..etc
you should check more information at https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/tracking_jank